# Display physical units in Azure Time Series Insights

Tags: azure, units-of-measurement, azure-timeseries-insights

The values and physical units (meter, seconds..) are forwarded from the Azure Event - Hub to the Azure Time Series Insights and are visible in the table for the displayed chart. [Screenshot of columns "Explore Raw Events" of a TSI - chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeNOT.png)

Nevertheless, it is not possible to select the column "unit" to be shown in the chart. [Selection of columns which can be selected to be shown in TSI- chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ekjw.png)

Therefore, only the purely numerical value without physical units is displayed in the TSI - chart.

Is there a way to include the units into the displayed values? not just as a title of an axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Autishofer, the "Show/Hide Columns" is used to show or Hide the instance properties (also referred as instance field) in the well. The little tabular column under the data trend is called "Well".
In you case, even though you are sending the units as part of the events JSON payload, it is **not stored** as instance filed; rather its stored as another variable /time series.

In my humble opinion, it doesn't make sense to send measurement units in every event, as its not going to change between events.
If I may recommend something, Please model the units as instance fields.